# How to shutdown/restart another windows PC using java?

Tags: java, windows, networking, restart, shutdown

I have 4 PC machine networked. Now I want to shutdown/restart them from my PC by using "PC Name" or "IP address". What should I do?
Below code is working to shutdown my own PC only .

```
public class shutdown {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
try
{
Process pr=rt.exec("cmd /c shutdown -s"); // for shutdown
Process pr1=rt.exec("cmd /c shutdown -r"); // for restart
Process pr2=rt.exec("cmd /c shutdown -l"); // for log off
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown) says , you must add /m \ComputerName

Comment: @user11786083 I think it will work.I'll try and say. Thank you very much